# Increase Internal Storage Space on Android Emulator

Tags: android-emulator

When I attempt to resize the internal storage for the emulator

./emulator -partition-size 1024

This is the error I receive: 2011-03-01 15:42:55.263 emulator[1033:903] LCC Scroll Enhancer loaded emulator: WARNING: ignoring locked user data image at /android-sdk-mac_x86/tools/./../platforms/.DS_Store/images/userdata-qemu.img emulator: WARNING: Another emulator is running. user data changes will NOT be saved emulator: ERROR: could not initialize user data image from /android-sdk-mac_x86/tools/./../platforms/.DS_Store/images/ramdisk.img: Not a directory

Any advice or help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

you can check [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2239330/how-to-increase-storage-for-android-emulator-install-failed-insufficient-stora) and [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2843322/how-to-increase-the-storage-space-in-android-emulator-installation-error-inst/18919778#18919778) for details about how to increase the internal storage of the Android emulator.

Comment: You should paste the pertinent information here, rather than leaving a link-only answer (see http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

It looks that for some reason the platform subdirectory is not correctly looked up and the first entry in the platforms directory is assumed to be one platform dir (whereas it is the .DS_Store file on MacOS). 
Just delete the .DS_Store file in the specified directory (using a rm command, not the Finder which will recreate it automatically) and it will workaround the problem.