# Installation error: INSTALL_FAILED_INSUFFICIENT_STORAGE? during running emulator

Tags: android, android-emulator, failed-installation

```
[2011-07-22 16:33:02 - Today] ------------------------------
[2011-07-22 16:33:02 - Today] Android Launch!
[2011-07-22 16:33:02 - Today] adb is running normally.
[2011-07-22 16:33:02 - Today] Performing com.horror.android.today.myMain activity launch
[2011-07-22 16:33:02 - Today] Automatic Target Mode: launching new emulator with compatible AVD 'google09'
[2011-07-22 16:33:02 - Today] Launching a new emulator with Virtual Device 'google09'
[2011-07-22 16:33:10 - Today] New emulator found: emulator-5554
[2011-07-22 16:33:10 - Today] Waiting for HOME ('android.process.acore') to be launched...
[2011-07-22 16:34:07 - Today] HOME is up on device 'emulator-5554'
[2011-07-22 16:34:07 - Today] Uploading Today.apk onto device 'emulator-5554'
[2011-07-22 16:35:12 - Today] Installing Today.apk...
[2011-07-22 16:35:31 - Today] Installation error: **INSTALL_FAILED_INSUFFICIENT_STORAGE**
[2011-07-22 16:35:31 - Today] Please check logcat output for more details.
[2011-07-22 16:35:32 - Today] Launch canceled!
```

**EDIT** 
I solved on emulator but on device , what is the solution? 
I follow this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4709137/solution-android-install-failed-insufficient-storage-error) but sometimes thats not best idea for me.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I follow following link, which has better to solve my problem.

http://google-androidlovers.blogspot.com/2011/07/solution-android-installfailedinsuffici.html

[Solution to INSTALL_FAILED_INSUFFICIENT_STORAGE error on Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4709137/solution-android-install-failed-insufficient-storage-error)

http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1201156

http://groups.google.com/group/android-developers/browse_thread/thread/41852900bd603070/583943d91dc9f754?lnk=gst&q=insufficient+memory&pli=1

Comment: Please copy and paste the main steps here as URLs can and have become invalid after a while

Answer (score 5):

you need to increase virtual memory of emulator

**How to increase virtual memory of emulator**

```
emulator -avd "Emulator Name" -partition-size 500
```

after then try to install your apk

if you got any error then see conversation of this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6743115/insufficent-storage-memory-message-while-install-50-mb-apk-in-emulator/6743176#6743176)

Answer (score 3):

I've had the same problem but on my phone (not emulator) when developing.

To solve it when it happens I go into Settings->Applications->Manage Applications -> The app I'm working with
and press Force Close, after that it works. For me this error occurs every 4-5 build, but using the Force close strategy makes it bearable (I used to restart the phone).

**Phone: Sony Ericsson Xperia Ray.

**Android Version: 4.0.3

Development Environment: Eclipse Ingido**

Answer (score 2):

An Android virtual device provides per default only 64M for the storaging Android applications. You can clean your installed application by re-starting the emulator and selecting the "Wipe user data" flag.

also you you can edit the emulation data partition size permanent  through avd manager -> emulator name -> edit -> hardware -> Ideal size of data partition = "2048"

Comment: Right clicking the device in Android Virtual Device Manager and choosing "Wipe user data" solved the problem for me, no restart (before) required. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If You are Installing the application to the Emulator then Some times it happend.
I face same Problem and i have solve it by my way.

In my Problem, I have install the application in emulator that is larger as like more then 10mb. And After that, i am going to Install another Application to that emulator and got this error..

Sollution:

I have just Restart the Eclipse that will erace all unwanted Memory and will get refresh to install the new Application.

Note: Its only works for some Normal perpose. as like to get error after installing another application. . .etc. Otherwise follow CapDroid's answer.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Just in case it helps for others.. I resolved it by wiping the emulator, and then restart

[image]