# Increasing the memory capacity of the android emulator?

Tags: android

How can the Android emulator's memory capacity be increased? I have a 16MB binary file which I have to parse. But when I execute a second time it says:

```
Installation error: INSTALL_FAILED_INSUFFICIENT_STORAGE.
```

Can anybody help please?

Comment: May want to look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2239330/how-to-increase-storage-for-android-emulator-install-failed-insufficient-storag

Comment: Also, bear in mind that Android devices have 16-24MB of heap space, and so you may not be able to parse that file in any case.

Comment: @Commonsware require your help on this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3584297/error-in-installation-of-an-application-on-sd-card-in-android-sdk-2-2 , please help me and catch me out

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7835609/android-4-0-emulator-out-of-space-error/7847148#7847148

Answer (score 9, accepted):

To summarize (and clarify), in Eclipse, go to "run Configurations". You can find that by right clicking on your project and click on "Run" and then "Run Configurations". Select "target", and select a preferred emulator target to launch. Then under "additional emulator command line options," add this:

-partition-size 1024

then click on apply and run.

Answer (score 0):

If you're targeting 2.2 platform you may force your app to install on SD card.