# Unable to upload file: No space left on device error in android

Tags: android

I am creating application which apk file now becomes 55 MB in size and cant install it on emulator and device both.

-how can i increase emulator size?

-what will be problem to upload on android market.

Thank You.
  Vikram

Comment: create an new device and sdk manager and set the SD card size to 500MB or above

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would say refactor your app, since an app that is 55MB on an Android device is not going to be usable by a lot of people - unless off course that is the intent.

Perhaps you can refactor it into a series of smaller "mini-apps" - that work in unison but can be installed as separate .apks?

You may also want to consider allowing the app to be installed on the SDCard - you can set that in the Android App Manifest using the "installLocation" tag.

Answer (score 1):

As you know, before Android 2.2 apps can not be installed on SD card. And max app size was around 25Mb. If you want application works at devices under 2.2, you need a downloader.
You can get details from [this discussion](http://www.google.com/support/forum/p/Android%20Market/thread?tid=5dcc15e4447fc01c&hl=en) at Android Market Forum.

You can set arbitrary size of emulator's flash, when create it in AVD Manager. 
 If you want increase inner memory size, please see [this topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2239330/how-to-increase-storage-for-android-emulator-install-failed-insufficient-storag).

Answer (score 1):

For me it was enough to delete the YOUR_PACKAGE_NAME.asec file in the emulator sd-card.

To find under DDMS -> FileExplorer -> mnt -> secure -> asec

After that I can upload the apk on the device again.