# Out of memory error on android emulator, but not on device

Tags: android, out-of-memory

On the Android Emulator, when I exit my app and run it again immediately, I get

```
OutOfMemoryError: bitmap size exceeds VM budget.
```

But on the device itself, this does not happen.  Why?

Comment: I think you are using static Bitmap array, which you not assigning to null after leaving activity. set that to null on closing activity.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

On a emulator the default max heap size is around 13MB.

On a device, it depends of the phone and of the android version. On my Motorola Droid, the max heap size is around 21-22MB and on my HTC Desire it's around 32MB.

That's why you have a crash on the emulator and not on your device.

If you want to monitor the heap size of your application you can call a similar method:

```
protected void displayMemoryUsage(String message) {
    int usedKBytes = (int) (Debug.getNativeHeapAllocatedSize() / 1024L);
    String usedMegsString = String.format("%s - usedMemory = Memory Used: %d KB", message, usedKBytes);
    Log.d(TAG, usedMegsString);
}
```

Comment: found out a big problem in my program, it uses way too much memory. 
I load a bitmap(478 KB) but it takes ~5000 KB to load it

Comment: It seems a bit too much memory for a single image. What is the resolution of this image and it's format? If you do not need the full resolution image in your app, did you consider reducing it's resolution or adding a inSampleSize in your BitmapFactory?

Answer (score 13):

Increase the AVD RAM and the max VM application heap size in VM options.

To do that, go to

Window-->AVD Manager-->Virtual Devices-->Edit.

Comment: its on 24. isn't it the same on the device?

Comment: well, I added it to 32 and now it works fine. but does all devices have this amount of memory?

Comment: Some sample max heap sizes:     G1 = 16 Mb
    Droid = 24 Mb
    Nexus One = 32 Mb
    Xoom = 48 Mb
    GalaxyTab = 64 Mb.

Answer (score 5):

You need to **increase heap size** for the emulator - it worked for me 
i increased it from **16 M to 32 M**

Answer (score 4):

Here is a lazy for how to find the options to manipulate heapsize for emulator from Andriod studio 1.2.0

1. Menu Tools->Android->AVD Manager
2. edit the virtual device of choice
3. click advanced settings and scroll down

[image: Change VM heap in android studio]

Answer (score 1):

Probably it is because you're device has more memory than your emulator. [This SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2239330/how-to-increase-storage-for-android-emulator-install-failed-insufficient-storag) shows you how to increase the size on your emulator.

Additionally you could [increase the Java VM Heap size](http://viralpatel.net/blogs/2009/01/jvm-java-increase-heap-size-setting-heap-size-jvm-heap.html).

Comment: Then try to increase the VM heap size: http://viralpatel.net/blogs/2009/01/jvm-java-increase-heap-size-setting-heap-size-jvm-heap.html

Answer (score 0):

Increase the size of memory allocated...