# Android Emulator: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError when manipulating a Bitmap

Tags: android, out-of-memory, image

I have a routine that manipulates a Bitmap to convert form RGB to Grayscale.

It works fine usually, but when I try to use it on a Bitmap which is 1088kb in size it gives me this Error:

```
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError
```

I am using the Emulator.  1088kb is not a very big picture, how can it be exhausting the memory?

To be precise the application that does invoke the problematic code includes another Activity on the back-stack that has a ListView of pictures thumbnails.

This is the method:

```
public Bitmap toGrayscale(Bitmap bmpOriginal)
{        
    int width, height;
    height = bmpOriginal.getHeight();
    width = bmpOriginal.getWidth();    

    Bitmap bmpGrayscale = Bitmap.createBitmap(width, height, Bitmap.Config.RGB_565);
    Canvas c = new Canvas(bmpGrayscale);
    Paint paint = new Paint();
    ColorMatrix cm = new ColorMatrix();
    cm.setSaturation(0);
    ColorMatrixColorFilter f = new ColorMatrixColorFilter(cm);
    paint.setColorFilter(f);
    c.drawBitmap(bmpOriginal, 0, 0, paint);
    return bmpGrayscale;
}
```

Comment: Bitmap size is 1088 kB or PNG file?

Comment: you need to .recycle() bitmaps when you are no using it, maybe you can recycle "originals" and keep grayscale in memory

Comment: @PaNaVTEC please how do I do it? Simply call recycle() on the Bitmap? Thanks!!!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are being very inefficient in managing bitmaps in memory and you likely have a memory leak (not freeing bitmaps from memory when you are done with them or keeping them around in activities that don't get garbage collected).  The Android Developers have a page for proper bitmap management:

http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/index.html

**You can try increasing the Heap size on your emulator.**

[Out of memory error on android emulator, but not on device](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7427587/out-of-memory-error-on-emulator-but-not-on-device)

**Monitor the heap size on your emulator:**

https://stackoverflow.com/a/7427803/445131

**Get rid of your memory leaks:**

[What Android tools and methods work best to find memory/resource leaks?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1147172/what-android-tools-and-methods-work-best-to-find-memory-resource-leaks)