# Outofmemoryerror on emulator with API level 15 only Android

Tags: java, android, memory, out-of-memory

I'm getting this error when trying to go go back to an Activity in my emulator with API level 15.

```
02-27 09:20:54.282: E/dalvikvm-heap(629): Out of memory on a 17040400-byte allocation.
02-27 09:20:54.343: E/AndroidRuntime(629): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
02-27 09:20:54.343: E/AndroidRuntime(629): java.lang.OutOfMemoryError
02-27 09:20:54.343: E/AndroidRuntime(629):  at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.nativeDecodeAsset(Native Method)
02-27 09:20:54.343: E/AndroidRuntime(629):  at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeStream(BitmapFactory.java:483)
02-27 09:20:54.343: E/AndroidRuntime(629):  at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeResourceStream(BitmapFactory.java:351)
02-27 09:20:54.343: E/AndroidRuntime(629):  at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeResource(BitmapFactory.java:374)
02-27 09:20:54.343: E/AndroidRuntime(629):  at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeResource(BitmapFactory.java:404)
02-27 09:20:54.343: E/AndroidRuntime(629):  at com.visma.sandbox.rotatingmenu.v.BitmapResourceSet.loadBitmap(BitmapResourceSet.java:92)
02-27 09:20:54.343: E/AndroidRuntime(629):  at com.visma.sandbox.rotatingmenu.v.BitmapResourceSet.loadAndCacheBitmap(BitmapResourceSet.java:84)
02-27 09:20:54.343: E/AndroidRuntime(629):  at com.visma.sandbox.rotatingmenu.v.BitmapResourceSet.load(BitmapResourceSet.java:49)
02-27 09:20:54.343: E/AndroidRuntime(629):  at com.visma.sandbox.RotatingMenuSurface.loadBitmapResourceSet(RotatingMenuSurface.java:118)
02-27 09:20:54.343: E/AndroidRuntime(629):  at com.visma.sandbox.RotatingMenuSurface.surfaceCreated(RotatingMenuSurface.java:69)
02-27 09:20:54.343: E/AndroidRuntime(629):  at android.view.SurfaceView.updateWindow(SurfaceView.java:533)
02-27 09:20:54.343: E/AndroidRuntime(629):  at android.view.SurfaceView.onWindowVisibilityChanged(SurfaceView.java:226)
02-27 09:20:54.343: E/AndroidRuntime(629):  at android.view.View.dispatchWindowVisibilityChanged(View.java:5839)
02-27 09:20:54.343: E/AndroidRuntime(629):  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchWindowVisibilityChanged(ViewGroup.java:945)
02-27 09:20:54.343: E/AndroidRuntime(629):  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchWindowVisibilityChanged(ViewGroup.java:945)
02-27 09:20:54.343: E/AndroidRuntime(629):  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchWindowVisibilityChanged(ViewGroup.java:945)
02-27 09:20:54.343: E/AndroidRuntime(629):  at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:965)
02-27 09:20:54.343: E/AndroidRuntime(629):  at android.view.ViewRootImpl.handleMessage(ViewRootImpl.java:2442)
02-27 09:20:54.343: E/AndroidRuntime(629):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
02-27 09:20:54.343: E/AndroidRuntime(629):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
02-27 09:20:54.343: E/AndroidRuntime(629):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4424)
02-27 09:20:54.343: E/AndroidRuntime(629):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
02-27 09:20:54.343: E/AndroidRuntime(629):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
02-27 09:20:54.343: E/AndroidRuntime(629):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
02-27 09:20:54.343: E/AndroidRuntime(629):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
02-27 09:20:54.343: E/AndroidRuntime(629):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
02-27 09:23:09.022: E/InputDispatcher(90): channel '41643028 com.visma.sandbox/com.visma.sandbox.IncomeInfoMenu (server)' ~ Channel is unrecoverably broken and will be disposed!
```

Max VM heap size is 48 and device ram size is 512 but the weird thing is that with a different emulator with the exact same heap size and memory size but with API Level 16 it works just fine. It also works on emulators with API level 8 with heap size of 24 and my real device with API level 10.

Is there something special with API level 15 or should I ignore this as a emulator bug?

Thanks for response.

Comment: Look are your memory usage and figure out if you have memory leaks or similar. I'd never ignore a OOME as they are really annoying buggers.

Comment: try reffering http://voices.yahoo.com/android-virtual-machine-vm-out-memory-error-7342266.html?cat=59 as i think its again a os bug in releasing bitmap alocations

Comment: Is it possible that the screen size that you have selected in the emulator is having an influence?

Answer (score -1):

Hi may be the issue is in Bitmap size or something or else Heap size is increase please check these posts this may be helpful to you

[Out of memory error on android emulator, but not on device](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7427587/out-of-memory-error-on-android-emulator-but-not-on-device)

[OutOfMemory exception when loading bitmap from external storage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4102758/outofmemory-exception-when-loading-bitmap-from-external-storage)

Comment: No, this crash is not dependent on the RAM and C drive space. It will be seen even on an actual device.