# Video in Android doesn't start (in res/raw folder) with VideoView or MediaPlayer

Tags: android, eclipse, android-virtual-device

First of all I have tried everything I could find on the web, but without success.

I'm trying to reproduce a video on AVD emulator (version 2.3.3). I've used both VideoView and MediaPlayer. The main problem is the following:

If I put some video file (mp4 format) on the directory res/raw and I try to run something (also an avoid program with only an Hello World TextView) in the console the running process blocks it on this line

```
Uploading Test.apk onto device 'emulator-5554'
```

I think that is a space problem (the video is 139MB) but also with a small wmv format (about 6MB) I've had the same issue.

I also have used [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2239330/how-to-increase-storage-for-android-emulator-install-failed-insufficient-stora) but it works only with mp3 file (even if only once).

Finally I've upgrade the RAM device up to 1024MB. Still nothing.

The code use in the onCreate method is

```
MediaPlayer mPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.video_file);
mPlayer.start();
```

I use eclipse IDE in Windows 7 x64.

Thanks for your attention.

P.s. The [logcat](http://baduel.altervista.org/stackoverflow/logcat_03112011.txt) (only warns and errors)

Edit: After 23 minutes the application is started but i listen only the audio but i don't see the video.

```
[2011-10-20 18:29:10 - TestActiveQoE] Uploading TestActiveQoE.apk onto device 'emulator-5554'
[2011-10-20 18:53:08 - TestActiveQoE] Installing TestActiveQoE.apk...
[2011-10-20 18:53:59 - TestActiveQoE] Success!
[2011-10-20 18:54:00 - TestActiveQoE] Starting activity qoe.test.TestActiveQoEActivity on device emulator-5554
[2011-10-20 18:54:01 - TestActiveQoE] ActivityManager: Starting: Intent { act=android.intent.action.MAIN cat=[android.intent.category.LAUNCHER] cmp=qoe.test/.TestActiveQoEActivity }
```

Comment: define "doesn't work" logcat logs, code .. answer to question: "does android support wmv format?"

Comment: You could register an OnErrorListener to get more info about errors.

Comment: And make sure you're using a supported format. Read here: http://developer.android.com/guide/appendix/media-formats.html

Comment: @Selvin Yes, Android [supports](http://javatech.org/2011/01/discovering-android-embedding-video-in-an-android-application/) wmv format. I will post the logcat soon.

Comment: @MisterSmith In any case I use always mp4 format.

Comment: @Baduel "(Yeah, wmv works surprisingly. avi and flv do not work )" on someones blog doesn't mean that it's true ... at least for all android devices(including emulators) see: http://developer.android.com/guide/appendix/media-formats.html

Comment: @Baduel Very likely the mp4 is actually encoded in a non-supported format. wmv is not officially supported. Anyway, don't expect to upload an apk to market above 50 MB.

Comment: @Selvin Yes, I agree with you. In any case I use an mp4 format (surely supported).

Comment: @MisterSmith I don't want to upload anything on Market. Only a test bed for my master thesis.