# com.android.ddmlib.SyncException: No space left on device in android

Tags: android

I have big size application when i run in emulator I got this exception

```
com.android.ddmlib.SyncException: No space left on device
```

can anybody tell how to solve this problem?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2239330/how-to-increase-storage-for-android-emulator-install-failed-insufficient-stora

Answer (score 1):

Open AVD Manager
Tools -> AVD Manager
Click On Edit Option Of Your Emulator From Actions Column On Right Side Of AVD Manager.
Its Open Virtual Device Configuration Window, Now Find "Show Advanced Setting" Button And It Will Show "Memory And Storage" Row Over There "Internal Storage" Have Some MB, So You Need To Increase It Like 2000,3000... And More
Than Finish It And Run Your Emulator Again Its Working Fine.

Answer (score 0):

Create the new emulator and give the more size or unistall all the applications in the old  emulator.

Comment: which size i will increase whether sdcard or heap size?

Answer (score 0):

Essentially, that means you have a memory problem. More than likely it is a leak.

First restart your phone and verify you are still getting the error. If so you are going to need to start digging in your code and find out where you are leaking!

Need more help? Post some code!

Switch DEBUG USB off and on again. It works for me. It seems to be some sort of problem with USB sync when debuggin in my device.

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

Install a new emulator then go to the advanced settings, find storage and memory and increase memory there.