# console error: Installation error: INSTALL_FAILED_INSUFFICIENT_STORAGE

Tags: android

I have 20 videos in my app(raw folder). I am trying to run my projects but my console indicate install_failed_insufficient_storage. I don't know what is the problem. I wish to show that videos thumbnails in grid view. please help what is problem....

Comment: Your Videos are exceeding the internal storage of device.... Create a folder on SDCard and copy those videos there...... you need to have dex and resources there....... better keep those heavy file on sd card if needed

Comment: @R Balaji you are test in emulator? or device?

Comment: @Dr.nik I'm testing in my emulator. It's possible store 20videos in my assets or raw. what is the capacity of the app.

Comment: ya you can store it and do it. what is total size?

Comment: you can increase emulator storage size

Comment: how to increase emulator storage size @Dr.nik

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2239330/how-to-increase-storage-for-android-emulator-install-failed-insufficient-stora

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. If you have installed an app with the same package name as yours, this would happen when the keys inside two apps are not the same.
2. As far as I know, if a package is too huge (greater than 50M), the system will refuse the installation. You mentioned that you had 20 videos inside, so this may be the root cause.

Answer (score 1):

- If you're using a real device, you've simply ran out of internal memory. Just go to Android settings > applications, and move some apps to the SD card or uninstall some apps.
- or in emulator, no space left in the sdcard so You need to increase the Android emulator's memory capacity, there are 2 ways for that:

1- Right click the root of your Android Project, go to "Run As" then go to "Run Configurations..." locate the "Android Application" node in the tree at the left, then select your project and go to the "Target" tab on the right side of the window look down for the "Additional Emulator Command Line Options" field (sometimes you'll need to make the window larger) and finally paste "-partition-size 1024" there. Click Apply and then Run to use your emulator.

2- Go to Eclipse's Preferences, then Select “Launch” Add “-partition-size 1024” on the “Default emulator option” field, then click “Apply” and use your emulator as usual.

Answer (score 0):

Clean and restart application. And another thing is that uninstall app if you have already installed.

Answer (score 0):

On a real device the only way I found to work around this problem is to uninstall my app and then reboot the device. it would work for 5 or 6 successive installs and then I had to do the reboot thing again.