# the application has stopped unexpectedly.

Tags: android

I am making a simple app in which the first activity has a button, which when clicked the second activity must be loaded. I have followed exactly what is mentioned in the video which I m referring but still my app is not running. not even the first button is appearing.

[2012-07-22 11:34:05 - MyFirstApp] Installation error: INSTALL_FAILED_INSUFFICIENT_STORAGE
[2012-07-22 11:34:05 - MyFirstApp] Please check logcat output for more details.
[2012-07-22 11:34:05 - MyFirstApp] Launch canceled!

is the error that i got.

In the logcat also there are ample of lines in red, but i dont know how to paste such a long logcat here..! i m using logcat for the first time.

Comment: i have four files. Main.java, its main.xml, Second.java and its second.xml

Comment: Are you using the emulator or a hardware device?

Comment: Then you're probably looking for [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2239330/how-to-increase-storage-for-android-emulator-install-failed-insufficient-stora). If none of those answers work, edit your original post with all the red lines from LogCat.

Comment: I tried it on a real device just now.. It didnt run.. but there were no errors while running the code on emulator.. just that it didnt work as required.

Answer (score 1):

The error message is self-explanatory. Your device has insufficient storage.