# Google TV emulator issue?

Tags: android, android-emulator, google-tv

I create google tv emulator and allocate 1024MB memory for sdcard as well.
but when I am running an basic Hello World example it responding me following error :

> [2012-10-23 17:36:26 - SampleTest] Failed to install SampleTest.apk on
>   device 'emulator-5554': Cannot allocate memory [2012-10-23 17:36:26 -
>   SampleTest] com.android.ddmlib.SyncException: Cannot allocate memory
>   [2012-10-23 17:36:26 - SampleTest] Launch canceled!

anyone have suggestion over this.

Answer (score 0):

The exception/error you are seeing has to do with a memory leak. I would suggest creating a new VM and only installing one app on it. How many applications are installed in the emulator now? How big is the SampleTest.apk?

If you get the same error then I would check that you have enough ram available in your host system (some times if you have a lot of files open you can run into issues with file descriptors). Check that you have allocated enough ram and sd space.

Comment: I try same..create new emulator but problem is same,sample apk is just of some KB.My system has 6 GB of RAM..so i don't think so it is because memory leak...any other suggestion.

Comment: Try setting -partition-size 1024 as explained here:
http://stackoverflow.com/a/3945915/251956