# In the Android KitKat x86 image, how can I increase the data partition size?

Tags: android, emulation, qemu

I'm having trouble increasing the size of the /data/ partition in the KitKat 4.4.2 x86 image. I've already tried editing the image size in the AVD GUI, and the solutions suggested here:
[How to increase storage for Android Emulator? (INSTALL_FAILED_INSUFFICIENT_STORAGE)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2239330/how-to-increase-storage-for-android-emulator-install-failed-insufficient-stora)

Does anybody have a tested, working method to increase the size of the data partition?

Comment: I am having the same problem with the ARM image - nothing seems to affect the size of the data partition.  I'll let you know if I find anything.