# How can I increase Emulator's RAM for Android Studio. Its disable right now. Is there any way to increase?

Tags: android-studio, android-emulator

I want to increase **Android Studio Emulator Ram**. But it is showing disable the option. Can any one help me?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you change your **Graphics to software**, Then you can edit the config and set the ram

[image]

Comment: That is also blocked bro. :(

Comment: what version on android are you using ?. The example which I gave, its `7.0 Nougat`

Comment: Android 9 (PIE)

Comment: have a look here. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2239330/how-to-increase-storage-for-android-emulator-install-failed-insufficient-stora

Comment: [Solved] By cloning solved this problem. Thanks for your help.