# After updating to Expo SDK 41 from Expo SDK 40, Android Studio won't start emulator

Tags: react-native, android-studio, android-emulator, expo

I go to start emulator on my mac m1 and it'll bring up the phone emulator however my project is not uploaded to the phone.

I am getting this error in the terminal:

› Opening on Android...
› Opening emulator Pixel_5_API_33
› Opening exp://172.16.100.190:19000 on Pixel_5_API_33
Couldn't start project on Android: Error running adb: adb: failed to install /Users/me/.expo/android-apk-cache/Exponent-2.19.7.apk: Failure [INSTALL_FAILED_INSUFFICIENT_STORAGE]
› Press ? │ show all commands

This download is taking longer than expected. You can also try downloading the clients from the website at https://expo.dev/tools
⠦ Installing Expo Go 2.19.7 on Pixel_5_API_33

The ios emulator seems to be working fine

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just solved this issue for myself, it appears your emulator doesn't have enough storage assigned to it.
[Here's how you can increase the storage on your emulator](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35828035)

For my emulator I increased the device `Internal Storage` to `8GB` and enabled `No SDCard`. This has allowed me to emulate my expo react-native app on Android while running on my M1 silicon chip MacBook.