# Error: ADB exited with exit code 1 Performing Streamed Install adb: failed to install ...\app.apk : Failure [INSTALL_FAILED_INSUFFICIENT_STORAGE]

Tags: android, apk, adb

```
Error: ADB exited with exit code 1
Performing Streamed Install

adb: failed to install C:\Users\Troy\StudioProjects\Test_app\build\app\outputs\flutter-apk\app.apk:
Failure [INSTALL_FAILED_INSUFFICIENT_STORAGE]
Error launching application on sdk gphone64 x86 64.
```

Comment: `INSTALL_FAILED_INSUFFICIENT_STORAGE` means there is not enough free storage on the  phone you want to install the APK file on.

Answer (score 0):

Go to the AVD Manager on Android Studio and edit the AVD you are using. Click Show Advanced Settings and find the settings Internal Storage and SD Card under Memory and Storage. Change the settings as desired. Click Finish and wipe the AVD by clicking the dropdown then Wipe Data.

[More Info](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35828035/12381757)

Answer (score 0):

Close your emulator , wait for about 10 seconds then cold boot it . This will work given that you don't have anything else other than the stock google apps on your emulator.